# Docker Desktop: In Windows 10, failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer

Tags: docker

I am tyring to create docker image for a Springboot application, after downloading and extracting openJdk, getting below issue

**failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\3d0aa48e2353f006d33c19a0aeabce1e899ae7c0ea8fcdba83b522bc4ab1bf4d: Access is denied.**

Below are details i have tried

Operating system: Windows 10 Pro

docker version : v19.03.5

docker configuration json file:

```js
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true
}
```

**Dockerfile:**

```js
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD /target/appcatalog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar appcatalog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "appcatalog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**docker command :** docker image build -t appcatalog-1 .

**Error**:
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer \?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\3d0aa48e2353f006d33c19a0aeabce1e899ae7c0ea8fcdba83b522bc4ab1bf4d: Access is denied.

Comment: Hi there, could you give some information on what you did, that caused this error.

Comment: Hi Michelle, i have updated issue with the steps i tried, could you please help

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Docker user. Hopefully with that extra information someone who is a Docker user can help.

Comment: Hi Michelle, issue resolved after below steps
1. Hyper-V and Containers Windows features enabling with below command from powershell:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
2. Reinstalled Docker windows

Comment: Hi glad to hear you solved it. Would you mind putting in the solution in more obviously. You are allowed to answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved after below steps

1. Hyper-V and Containers Windows features enabled with below command from powershell:

```
     Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V All
```

2. Reinstalled Docker Desktop

Comment: I can't edit the answer for a one-letter change, but `All` needs to be `-All`: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

Comment: You may also need to enable containers alongside Hyper-V: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All`

Comment: I think both in same command is also valid:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All`