# Dockerfile build failed: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: docker

I have written a very simple `Dockerfile` which is using node image and simply installing a package globally. I am trying to build the docker file with command `docker build . -t img-name` but it keeps crashing:

```
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: Failed to safefile.OpenRelative failed in Win32: open \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\20b4651bca2259bb1726394c32064eb175f6fd838a7efb57040de6774d376985\usr\share\man\man7\pam.7.gz: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0x1f) usr\share\man\man7\pam.7.gz
```

Setup Details:

- Windows 10
- Docker Desktop 3.6.0
- Using Windows Container
- I have set `Use the WSL 2 based engine`
- I have ran the command in Powershell Admin `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All;` which return `Online` as `True` and `RestartNeeded` as `False`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Desktop: In Windows 10, failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessBaseLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872388/docker-desktop-in-windows-10-failed-to-register-layer-re-exec-error-exit-sta)